# Set or update dictionary entries code pattern in Python

Tags: python, design-patterns, dictionary

Given a dict with the following format:

```
dict_list = {key0: [list0,list1], key1: [list0,list1], ...}
```

I am currently updating `dict_list` in the following manner:

```
for key in list_of_possibly_new_keys:
   if key not in dict_list.keys():
      dict_list[key] = [list0, list1]
   else:
      dict_list[key][0].extend(list0)
      dict_list[key][1].extend(list1)
```

Is there a way to make this code shorter using native constructs (i.e. no additional methods)?  I am increasingly encountering this data "set or update" pattern in my code, and wondering whether there is a more concise way to do this.

UPDATE/CLARIFICATION:

Sample actual contents of dict_list:

```
dict_list = {'John Solver': [['05/10/2013','05/14/2013','05/22/2013'],[20.33,40.12,10.13]]}
```

Where the floats could represent John Solver's daily expenses in US dollars.

If possible, we'd like to keep using two long lists instead of many date-expense pairs, as we'd like to conveniently perform a sum of expenses operation using sum(dict_list['John Solver'][1]).

Comment: can you provide a small sample input and the expected result, I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Initial tip: you can do `if key not in dict_list` for a set-based lookup rather than calling `dict_list.keys()` which returns a list

Comment: [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)?

Comment: @HenryH I've updated my question with a specific example already

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`dict.setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
for key in list_of_possibly_new_keys:
      dict_list.setdefault(key,[]).extend([list0, list1])
```

**help** in `dict.setdefault`:

```
>>> dict.setdefault?
Type:       method_descriptor
String Form:<method 'setdefault' of 'dict' objects>
Namespace:  Python builtin
Docstring:  D.setdefault(k[,d]) -> D.get(k,d), also set D[k]=d if k not in D
```

Comment: @Michael since `dict_list` is actually a dictionary, it works. `setdefault` is a method for any dictionary.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Actually there was a typo, I typed `dict.detdefault`.

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly with a little modification: dict_list.setdefault(key,[[],[]])[0].extend(list0)

Answer (score 7):

Unless this is homework, why can't you use a `defaultdict` here?

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict_list = defaultdict(list)

for key in list_of_possibly_new_keys:
    dict_list[key] += [list0, list1]
```

Updated for your example:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dict_list = defaultdict(lambda :[[], []])
>>> dict_list['John Solver'][0].append('05/10/2013')
>>> dict_list['John Solver'][1].append(20.33)
and so on
```

Aside: Turns out that due to the limited precision of floats, it's usually a terrible idea to use them to represent currency. Consider using the `decimal` module instead

Comment: Thank you, this is a great tip. I'm having trouble applying it in my application though (please see UPDATE section), as I am extending not the list indexed by the key, but rather the list within it. (dict_list[key][0].extend(list0) and not dict_list[key].extend(list0))

Comment: @silvernightstar, It's just necessary to pass the right function to defaultdict. It should be a function with no parameters that returns the default value. In this case a list containing two empty lists

Comment: @gnibbler Thank you for the update. I've verified that it also works perfectly. I'm pickling my data though, and I've discovered that using defaultdict incurs some penalty (around 25% larger file size) compared to using the more native dict. So, I'll stick to setdefault for now. Thanks again!

Comment: @gnibbler UPDATE: Penalty seems to be just a constant regardless of number of entries. For bigger data sets, this would be negligible. Thinking of using defaultdict instead.

Comment: Penalty removed by pickling dict(dict_list) as opposed to simply dict_list.